# Facebook Graph API - how to get total share count of a video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find a way to get only the total number of shares of a video post, using version Graph API v2.9.

The *sharedposts* endpoint return full post object, and only batches of 8. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/sharedposts/

The *?fields=shares* parameter, can't be apllied on video objects.

Is there a way to get this data?

(p.s: I wanted to tag this question also with facebook-graph-api-v2.9, but this tag still does not exist, and I don't have enough reputation to create the new tag, if someone may add this tag please).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only `video_id` as endpoint, use `{page_id}_{video_id}/?fields=shares`